# How to run a program in KDE4 Dolphin?

Tags: kde4, dolphin

In KDE4, in Dolphin, when I double-click a program (with execute bit set), Dolphin asks me what I want to use to open the file.  I just want to run it.

When I right-click, I get a list of stuff, but no "Execute" option.

How do I just run a program in Dolphin?

Comment: Does the program start from the konsole/terminal ?

Comment: @user26687: Yes.

Comment: How is the Dolphin identifying the file type when you move the mouse cursor over the program icon ? Executable, Shell/Python/Perl/ script or something else ?

Comment: "shared library" followed by the size.

Comment: Does your program have an extension ? The .so or something else ? What if you remove the extension ?

Comment: No, no extensions. It's just a regular binary executable, like ANY in ANY linux system.

Comment: Doesn't run executable shell scripts either. These run find from command-line.

Answer (score 0):

Change permissions for the file to tell to your system that the file is a runnable file.

By console:

```
chmod +x filename
```

Or right click on the file, properties, permissions.

Comment: This is already done. The execute bit is set, and I have permissions to run it. Dolphin won't.